# How can a service transfer a generic JsonPatchDocument<> to another service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, microservices, autorest

I have built an application running on Azure (ASP.Net Core 2.1) that involves microservices and a client application:

> Client app (Android) --calls--> microservice A (gateway) --forwards->
>   microservice B

In the microservice **B**, I have the following method defined in an `Controller`:

```
[HttpPatch]
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = nameof(PatchEntityAsync))]
[Route(ApiConstants.Constraints.ControlId, Name = nameof(PatchEntityAsync))]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent, "Result of the patch")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[Consumes(MediaTypes.Application.JsonPatch)]
public async Task PatchEntityAsync(string tenantId, Guid entityId, JsonPatchDocument<EntityModel> entityUpdates)
{
   //
}
```

The method accepts a `JsonPatchDocument` to apply on an `EntityModel`. After generating the swagger and running autorest, I get the following auto generated method:

```
Task<HttpOperationResponse> PatchEntityWithHttpMessagesAsync(string tenantId, System.Guid controlId, IList<Operation> entityPatches = default(IList<Operation>), Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

This auto generated client is being used by microservice **A** who has a similar Controller that accepts a JsonPatchDocument.

**Problem**

However, it seems that I have lost the type constraint: it is no longer advertised that microservice **B** requires a list of updates on an `EntityModel` type.

**Question**

How can microservice **A** transfer a generic `JsonPatchDocument<>` to microservice **B** without having to manipulate the data?